# Method peripheral: didWriteValueForCharacteristic: error: is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, mtu

I send data over BLE using the following call

```
[peripheral writeValue:dataPiece forCharacteristic:characteristic
    type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

when the dataPiece size is `180 bytes` or less everything works fine: accepting device receives all the data, on calling device corresponding callback (`peripheral: didWriteValueForCharacteristic: error:`) is called. When the size goes large (`>180`) receiving device still gets all the data (in two chunks: of `180 bytes` and the rest). However in the latter case the callback on transmitting device is not called.

Also `[peripheral maximumWriteValueLengthForType:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse]` returns `512` which is more than `180`, so I would expect `200` to work fine.

Am I missing something (obviously yes, but what)?

Comment: By mistake, I've tried to write MTU-Size bytes to the characteristic and experienced the very same result, as you did (callback not beeing called at all). After changing the write size to MTU-3, everything works well. Thanks a lot for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

For peripheral, it should respond descriptor when central call `readValueForDescriptor:` method.
If it did not respond, central can not write data to it.

See:

- `(void)readValueForDescriptor:(CBDescriptor *)descriptor;`
- `(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForDescriptor:(CBDescriptor *)descriptor error:(nullable NSError *)error;`